# jquery append <div> based on the viewport and ajax refresh on browser resize

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi a jQuery newbie question. I am trying to add different sidebars based on browser view-port.

**Here is my script:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Viewport Test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadPage(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);

    if (width > 1440) {
        $('#aside').load('widepage.php');
    } else if (width >= 1024 && width <= 1440) {
        $('#aside').load('narrowpage.php');
    } 
}

$(function() {
   reloadPage($(this).width());
   $(window).resize(function() {
       reloadPage($(this).width());
   });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Here I want to append the external php Script -->

    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**What i need to do is :**

1. Ajax load these sidebars while rest of the page continues loading.
2. I do not want to load them into a div but **APPEND** them before `<div id="content"></div>`
3. I want the php scripts in various files to be appended and not the output.
4. On browser resize, only the appended part should reload.

**My Question:**

Am I doing the right way? If not what is the correct way. Please explain with code illustrations as I am totally new to JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by #3? You want the PHP code to show as plain text?

Comment: @Michael No I want the php script to execute and do what it is suppose to do. Like `<?php require_once 'filename';?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your main goal is to have 3 different sized sidebars. I am under the impression you still want them BEFORE the content div. You will need to put a  in the location you want the sidebar to appear. Otherwise, there is no good way to flush the current sidebar and load the new one.

I believe to accomplish what you are trying to do, you need to have some knowledge of the currently loaded sidebar, and only change it if the page has been resized into a different category. For this example, we'll assume the first sidebar is for 0-1023 pixel windows, medium is 1024-1599, and wide is 1600+.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var curwidth, script, prevclass, newclass;

function reloadBars(width) {
    width = parseInt(width, 10);
    newclass = ""

    if (width < 801 && (curwidth == -1 || curwidth > 800)) {
        newclass = 'bar-0';
        bar = '800.php';
    } else if ((width > 800 && width < 1201) && (curwidth < 800 || curwidth > 1201)) {
        newclass = 'bar-1';
        bar = '1000.php';
    } else if ((width > 1200 && width < 1601) && (curwidth < 1200 || curwidth > 1601)) {
        newclass = 'bar-2';
        bar = '1200.php';
    } else if (width > 1600 && curwidth < 1600) {
        newclass = 'bar-3';
        bar = '1600.php';
    } else {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: bar,
        data: {},
        success: 
        function(response) {

            $('#aside').html(response);
            $('#aside').addClass(newclass);
            $("#aside").removeClass(prevclass);
            prevclass = newclass;
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("UH OH! Error!");
        }
    });
    curwidth = width;
}
prevclass = ""
curwidth = -1;
reloadBars($(this).width());

   $(window).resize(function() {
       reloadBars($(this).width());
   });
});
```

Comment: OH NO! My first paragraph should have said 'You need to add a `<div id="sidebar"></div>` where you want the sidebar to show. Or you need to change `$("#sidebar")` to `$("#aside")` if that is where you want the content to show up'  Viewing your page, it is working properly, you just don't have a div with the id of 'sidebar' for the content to be inserted into.

Comment: Yes, if you add the `<div id="sidebar"></div>` before the `<div id="content"></div>`. In the CSS for "#sidebar", make it `float:left` you may have to `position:relative` on `#sidebar` and `#content`. Then change the part in the ajax code back to `$("#sidebar").html(response)`

Comment: I know your widepage.php was creating all three sizes, but that is a php issue rather than JavaScript. The normal page is working on my iPhone, but I can't check the widepage

Comment: My mistake. Normalpage.php and widepage.php echo multiple sidebars.

Comment: If you are using `$('#sidebar').html(response)` it will replace the content within the sidebar div

Comment: It appears you have not added `<div id='sidebar'></div>` within your wrapper div. are you still using `.before()` in the Ajax success function?

Comment: What I'm saying is you need to add the sidebar div to the original php file (the one that has the wrapper, content, and aside divs which JavaScript can fill with the desired content.

Comment: You can, but the div should resize itself according to the content within it.

Comment: You should add a prevclass and newclass variable and set the newclass variable in the if/else. Then after the .html() in the Ajax success function, call `$("#sidebar").addClass(newclass)` and `$("#sidebar").removeClass(prevclass)`, then `prevclass = newclass` all within the success function. Set prevclass to "" at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Can you add `alert('New: ' + newclass + ' Prev: ' + prevclass)` after `$('#aside').html(response)`

Comment: Oh wait, I know what the problem is. Add `prevclass, newclass` to the variable declaration with `curwidth, script`. Set both to "" before calling the `reloadBars()` for the first time (down where `curwidth=-1`). Then remove the `prevclass = ""` in the reloadBars function. What is happening is prevClass is being reset to "" every time the function is called, so there is no knowledge of which class to remove. Each time `removeClass()` is called, it is being passed `prevclass` which has been set to "".

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. I've edited my answer to reflect the changes I think should do the trick. I started with your latest code, so it should copy and paste right in.

Comment: Can you send me the ftp details again? I don't remember the host.

Comment: Take a look now. Is this the action you want? I'm not quite sure the details, but it seems it was a variable scope issue. I moved the newclass declaration into reloadBars() and it works. I also added #aside before the .bar-<#> in the CSS, as you wont get the color change without it because of the rules of CSS.

Comment: Not a problem. I just like building websites :)

Answer (score 0):

2) Jquery has a .before() function for inserting before elements: http://api.jquery.com/before/

```
sidebar = "<p>This is the sidebar</p>"
$("#content").before(sidebar)
```

3) PHP will be executed by an AJAX request (which jQuery makes easy)

```
function reloadPage(width) {
    var script

    width = parseInt(width)

    if(width < 1024)
        return
    else if(width < 1440)
        script = 'narrowpage.php'
    else
        script = 'widepage.php'

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: script,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            //check to make sure data is OK

            $('#content').before(response)
        },
        error: function (ts) {
            alert("Uh Oh! AJAX failed!")

        }
    })
}
```

You may have a scope issue if the reloadPage function is outside $(function() { }), but otherwise the function should work as you want.

With the 'type', you can do a GET or POST request just like a form submission.

```
echo $_POST["foo"];
```

would echo 'bar', which would then be appended before the content div.

Comment: OOPS! `$('#content').before(...` Fixed again. Is `'#aside'` where you want the content to appear? If so, `$('#aside').html(response)` would do the trick.

Comment: On that page. If you're browser is fullscreen (>1600), no sidebar will show. If you look at the page with firebug (on firefox), you'll see the ajax call with no page script, which means you did not set the `script` variable. If you want to limit the sidebar to window size up to 1600, you need to return before the ajax call in the case that the window is too large. `if (width > 1600) return`

Comment: Please see my next answer, writing it now.